# How do I SHOW TABLES in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I'm trying to do a `SHOW TABLES` command in my Oracle Database 19c as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tools/rtoolsijcomrefshow.html#rtoolsijcomrefshow__showtables).

But when I run that command all I see in the output of SQL Developer is this:

> Show tables handled.

How can I get `SHOW TABLES` to give me a list of tables in the schema?

Comment: Doesn't SQL Developer already show you a list of tables?

Comment: Oh it does. Ok thanks. Sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you referenced is not for Oracle 19c; it is for a defunct project that is completely unrelated. Oracle database does not have a `SHOW TABLES` command. Depending on what you're looking for, you would need to select from one of the following data dictionary views to get a list of tables:

- [USER_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/USER_TABLES.html#GUID-564CEA73-E79E-4664-AC32-0CBAB817CF5A) - contains info on the current user's tables
- [ALL_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_TABLES.html#GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D) - contains info on all tables that the current user has privileges to access
- [DBA_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_TABLES.html#GUID-480A67CD-39FD-40B8-9395-164E92E439E6) - contains info on all tables in the instance, but requires elevated privileges to access

For example:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

For more information on the data dictionary, check out the correct Oracle 19c documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/index.html

As another example, if you're trying to confirm the existence of a table named "EMPLOYEE", you could run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
```